# Autowired en SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Buenas a todos.

Me tope con el siguiente problema en un proyecto Spring boot.  Cuando yo tengo un @ServiceController  puedo llamar a todos los beans @Component y @Autowired que tengo.
Ahora si yo quiero hacerlo desde el método main de la clase @SpringBootApplication tengo que definir el archivo applicationContext.xml y declar que voy a usar @Autowired
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.miejemplo.miejemplodev"/>`

luego instanciar el applicationContext
`ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");`

para poder usar mis beans.

Alguien sabe si se puede usar al igual que en un @ServiceController sin definir el applicationContext.xml y sin instanciar un applicationContext ?

En mi caso lo intenté pero me quedan en null los beans.

Desde ya muchas gracias.